# Problem with passing an int from an activity to another caused by the defaultValue

Tags: java, android

When I try to pass an int from an activity to another the receiver gets the default value every time.

This is my code from the sender activity

```
Intent go = new Intent(this,BattleActivity.class);
go.putExtra("Tag", tag);
startActivity(go);
```

and this is the code from the receiver activity

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("Tag", 0);

tagView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tag);
tagView.setText("The selected number is " + intValue);
```

Comment: is value assingned to `tag` in first activity? log the value before you send it to next activity.

Comment: This code looks ok.  Are you sure the value of `tag` is not 0 at the time of storing it in the intent extras? You can also try `mIntent.getExtras().getInt("Tag")` - but that should give you the same value anyway.

Comment: Where do you call putExtra() and getIntent()? In onCreate?

Comment: show me your tag, where you assingned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably **this** from :

```
Intent go = new Intent(this,BattleActivity.class);
```

Instead, try:

```
Intent go = new Intent(SenderActivity.this, BattleActivity.class);
```

Comment: sender and reciever is just name for example not class.

Comment: ok, I got you. then try using bundle instead if this is not working

Comment: i am not that person who asked this question.